# Redux change to nested object not triggering componentDidUpdate in component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am struggling to figure out why a change to an object located in the store handled by a redux reducer is not triggering the `componentDidUpdate` method inside of my react component.  I am using the react developer tools and can see the correct store after the state is reduced, and am also using redux logger and can see the correct after state after the reducer makes the change.  But the component still never calls the update method.

**action**

```
export const GSAP_ANIMATION = 'GSAP_ANIMATION';
export const animateGsap = (key, next) => {
  return {
    type: GSAP_ANIMATION,
    payload: {
      key: key,
      next: next
    }
  }
}
```

**reducer**

```
case GSAP_ANIMATION:
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    ...state,
    gsap: {
      ...state.gsap,
      [payload.key]: {
        ...state.gsap[payload.key],
        next: {
          ...payload.next
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

**component connection**

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    component: state.priorities.gsap[ownProps.id]
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    addGsap: (key) => dispatch(actions.addGsap(key))
  };
}

GsapComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(GsapComponent);
```

In the GsapComponent I have the `componentDidUpdate` method, but this method is never called.  However, I can see that the value of `this.props.component` should be correct when I view the component in the chrome extension.

**edit**

also doing `{ JSON.stringify(this.props.component) }` correctly shows the updated prop values.  Nothing in the react component update lifecycle is every triggered though.

I have also tried to use the immutibility-helper from react like so

```
return update(state, {
    gsap: {
      [payload.key]: {
        $merge: { next: payload.next }
      }
    }
  });
```

but it still doesn't call the lifecycle method.

[GsapComponent source code](https://gist.github.com/kyle-mccarthy/00f29f0789d3b40f52f9ff438822e038).

Comment: Can you show important for this question component code?

Comment: @MaciejSikora i am sorry I am not sure what you mean by "important" can you clarify and I would be happy to update the question? Thanks!

Comment: just show component code to see full picture

Comment: @MaciejSikora I have added it as a gist to keep the original question from getting too long https://gist.github.com/kyle-mccarthy/00f29f0789d3b40f52f9ff438822e038

Comment: @MaciejSikora high level overview is that I am attempting to perform animations using Greensock that persist through state changes, right now they get removed from the dom when a rerender occurs.

Comment: Question is componentDidMount code inside if is running? Next question what is initial state? Maybe initial state has the value and component not trigger the addGsap?

Comment: componentDidMount code does run, the component is mounted by its parent.  But in the initial state gsap is initialized as an empty object, then as components are mounted they are added to the gsap object by their ID, then the current animation is tracked in the object associated by the ID and style is updated once the animation is done.  so `gsap: { [some id added during mount]: { next: {}, style: {} } }`

Answer (score 0):

Check this [object assign documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign). Section Examples -> Warning for Deep Clone. I think that your reducer return object is === as state object so react can't detect change. Try json.parse(json.stringify) workaround or use [immutable-js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/).

Comment: I am sure that his reducer is returning new reference.

Comment: check my update, I have also tried to call use the immutability helpers, but nothing